# Blazor OIDC Authentication popup

Tags: blazor, identityserver4, openid-connect

## Problem

When I'm trying to use the `RemoteAuthenticatorView` in combination with OIDC, the page only redirects to the identityserver4 website

## Expected outcome

A popup should be opened with the identityserver's content.

---

In contrast, AddMsalAuthentication provides a `options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode` ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-5.0#login-mode-1))

Is there something similar for `AddOidcAuthentication` ?

Resources that I use to reproduce this issue:

- https://medium.com/@marcodesanctis2/securing-blazor-webassembly-with-identity-server-4-ee44aa1687ef
- https://github.com/cradle77/BlazorSecurityDemo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Identity Server 4 comes with a standard set of cshtml files.
It hasn't any "popup" ready mode out of the box.

If you want to implement the same behaviour as MSAL, you need to develop an integration via javascript like the one referenced in the index.html when you use Azure AD B2C authentication with Blazor.

Comment: Another step down in to the rabbit hole. Don't suppose you could elaborate or link steps to achieve the above?